# C# generics is keyword covariance / contravariance type inferral

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

Please consider this interface:

```
public interface IInitialiazableEntity<TRepository> where TRepository : class, IRepository
{
    void Initialize(TRepository repository);
}
```

This class (snippet):

```
public class SomeFacade<TRepository> where TRepository : class, IRepository
{
        public void Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : AbstractEntity
        {
            try
            {
                if (entity is IInitialiazableEntity<TRepository>)
                    (entity as IInitialiazableEntity<TRepository>).Initialize(this.Repository);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Logger.Error(ex);
            }
        }
}
```

And the entity:

```
public class Student : AbstractEntity, IInitialiazableEntity<IRepository>
{ 
    void Initialize(IRepository repository) { ... }
}
```

Since the student is only `IInitialiazableEntity<IRepository>` and the facade will have an actual repository which is more specialized than the basic `IRepository` (i.e. it will be `IMySpecialRepository : IRepository`), will the `is` keyword realize that it can cast the `IMySpecialRepository` and pass it to the `Initialize` method of the entity? Or if not, how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried it? Also, what are IMySpecialRepository and IMySpecializedRepository?

Comment: I am sorry, I know I can test this, and then try find a solution, but I'm in an extra hurry. And I think It will be useful for other people (given the title/tags are right).

Comment: @ken2k the special(ized) repository (there was a typo, both are the same, I corrected it) - is anything inheriting from the base IRepository.

Comment: Sure you can do it. The thing is, should you? The actual type should be none of your concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, if you had an instance `SomeFacade<IMySpecialRepository>` the code will not work.

You have two options, one is the answer provided by Dan Bryant, the other is to make `IInitialiazableEntity<TRepository>` contravariant.

Your interface declaration will become (note the `in` on the generic type):

```
public interface IInitialiazableEntity<in TRepository> where TRepository : class, IRepository
{
    void Initialize(TRepository repository);
}
```

This will allow your `is` check and cast to work, as `IInitialiazableEntity<IRepository>` can be cast to `IInitialiazableEntity<IMySpecialRepository>` when using a contravariant generic.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) for more information about Covariance and Contravariance in generics.

Comment: Thank you Sir, that one in makes all the difference. I never would've went this way hadn't I asked. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your entity is of type Student, the 'is' will return false; this is because Student doesn't implement the more specific interface specialization.  You don't need to cast to this more specific interface, though.  This should work just fine:

```
public class SomeFacade<TRepository> where TRepository : class, IRepository
{
        public void Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : AbstractEntity
        {
            try
            {
                if (entity is IInitialiazableEntity<IRepository>)
                    (entity as IInitialiazableEntity<IRepository>).Initialize(this.Repository);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Logger.Error(ex);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: But the Student entity might use the basic IRepository, while some other entity might implement IInitialiazableEntity with a more specialized repository, thus I need to support it.

Comment: But the top of the inheritance will be the TRepository that the facade has. No entity will use a more specialized repo than the facade. Or I can just make the entities have to implement the initializable with the most specialized repo, and be done with it, then the is will return true.. what do you think?